# Import a txt file into a 2d list of floats

Tags: python, file, text

I ve got a txt file of float numbers and I want to opened it in a python script into a 2d list of floats.How is it possible to store a txt to 2d list of float? I am using the following code:

```
arrays = []
for line in open('normRowsRaw.txt'):
# use a list comprehension to build your array on the fly
      new_array = np.array((array.float(i) for i in line.split(' '))) 
      arrays.append(new_array)
```

and my file is like the above series:

```
0.0098506, 0.068954, 0.007388, 0.0049253, 0.0049253, 0.054178, 0.014776, 0.014776,  
0.014776, 0.0024627, 0.007388, 0.0098506, 0.007388, 0.022164, 0.029552, 0.017239, 
0.0024627, 0.019701, 0.0098506, 0.0024627, 0, 0.068954, 0.0098506, 0.11082, 0.0024627...
```

Comment: Does your file contains equal number of items on each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
arrays = []
with open('normRowsRaw.txt') as f:
    f = f.read().split(',')
    for n in f:
        arrays.append(float(n.strip()))
```

### Edit

this appends to a normal list not 2d

Comment: AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to convert each string to float and return the 2D array as a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
with open('normRowsRaw.txt') as file:
    array2d = np.array([[float(digit) for digit in line.split(",")] for line in file])
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.0098506,
which is the first element

Comment: What if I wanted array2d and array2d[i] to be list type?

Comment: Is your file just 1 long line of comma delimited values, or are there line breaks? If there are line breaks, this should give you a 2D numpy array.

Comment: Actually the size of file 360x339

Answer (score 0):

This is the way is would do it:

```
for line in open('normRowsRaw.txt'):
    # use a list comprehension to build your array on the fly
    array = line.split(',')
    del array[len(array)-1] #to remove \n from array

    new_array = []
    for i in range(0,len(array)-1):
       new_array.append(float(array[i]))
    #After all elements are added to an array, add array to result
    arrays.append(new_array)
```